# writing node.js layer to send MMS message to Api.ai/DialogFlow

Tags: twilio, dialogflow-es, mms

Right now twilio does not send MMS message to API.ai, it only sends an event if text is sent to the bot, I am trying to build a webhook that will pass that along with the text.  I am trying to build off of this repo https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-nodejs-client/tree/master/samples/twilio if anyone knows how to go about this or if anyone else has a repo where they have successfully done that, it would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It's not that Twilio doesn't send MMS messages to API.ai, but the example application doesn't do so.

[As you can see here](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/twilio/bot/src/twiliobot.js#L68-L72) the code that processes the message just looks for `req.body.Body` which is the text in the message. If you want to also send images to API.ai then you need to also look at `req.body.NumMedia` which will tell you how many images were sent and then `req.body.MediaUrl0` for the first image (and `req.body.MediaUrl{N}` for the Nth image).

As far as I can tell from the API.ai documentation there's no way to pass an image to an API.ai agent though. They seem to deal with text only (but can return images to you).

Let me know if this helps at all.